# Show y axis for psaxes starting from 130

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I have a graph like this:

[image]

However, when I plot it out on LaTex, it turns out like this:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psset{xunit=0.13cm,yunit=0.5cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(122.,-2.)(182.,11.)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=5.,Dy=1]{->}(0,0)(122.,-2.)(182.,11.)
\psline(135.,0.)(135.,7.)
\psline(140.,0.)(140.,7.)
\psline(140.,7.)(135.,7.)
\psline(145.,0.)(145.,4.)
\psline(145.,4.)(140.,4.)
\psline(150.,0.)(150.,9.)
\psline(145.,4.)(145.,9.)
\psline(145.,9.)(150.,9.)
\psline(155.,0.)(155.,5.)
\psline(155.,5.)(150.,5.)
\psline(160.,0.)(160.,2.)
\psline(160.,2.)(155.,2.)
\psline(170.,0.)(170.,1.)
\psline(165.,0.)(165.,1.)
\psline(165.,1.)(170.,1.)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}
```

How do I make the y-axis appear?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in a `pgfplots` solution which is quite short:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=0, xmin=122, xmax=182,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,font=\scriptsize] 
            \addplot[ybar interval] coordinates {%
                (135,7) (140,4) (145,9) (150,5) (155,2) (160,0) (165,1) (170,0)
                };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,Dx=5,]{->}(130,0)(122,-2)(182,11.)
```

the first pair of coordinates defines the intersection of the axes.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when I changed (0,0) to (130,0), it gave me the x-axis starting from 0, 5, 10 and so on. Would like it to start from 130, 135, 140 and so on.

Comment: use `Ox=130` for the start value